# Get from ByteBuffer to byte[] does not write to byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, bytebuffer

I'm consecutively reading blocks of BLOCKSIZE (e.g. 512) bytes from a SocketChannel into a ByteBuffer. I'd then like to append the ByteBuffer content to a byte[] and go for the next round. The result would be a byte[] containing all the bytes that were read from the SocketChannel.

Now, System.arraycopy(...) works as expected. But when I use ByteBuffer's get(result, offset, length), nothing is written. The result array values remain zeroed.

Why is that?

```
  public final static int BLOCKSIZE = 512;

  public byte[] getReceivedData() {
    int offset = 0, read;
    byte[] result = {};
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(BLOCKSIZE);
    try {
      while (true) {
        read = _socketChannel.read(buffer);
        if (read < 1) {
          // Nothing was read.
          break;
        }

        // Enlarge result so we can append the bytes we just read.
        result = Arrays.copyOf(result, result.length + read);

        // This works as expected.
        System.arraycopy(buffer.array(), 0, result, offset * BLOCKSIZE, read);

        // With this, however, nothing is written to result. Why?
        buffer.get(result, offset * BLOCKSIZE, read);

        if (read < BLOCKSIZE) {
          // Nothing left to read from _socketChannel.
          break;
        }

        buffer.clear();
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
  }
```

**EDIT:**

I noticed `offset++` was missing, too. So if there is more than `BLOCKSIZE` bytes on the channel, things get messed up...

Anyways, `ByteArrayOutputStream` really makes things simpler there so I decided to use that.

Working code:

```
  public byte[] getReceivedData() {
    int read;
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(BLOCKSIZE);
    try {
      while (true) {
        buffer.clear();
        read = _socketChannel.read(buffer);
        if (read < 1) {
          break;
        }
        result.write(buffer.array(), 0, read);
        if (read < BLOCKSIZE) {
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result.toByteArray();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `flip()` the buffer before the `get()`, and `compact()` it afterwards.

If `read == -1` you need to not only break out of the loop but close the channel too.

Comment: `flip()` did the trick, thanks. I think `compact()` is not required though. After `get()`ing everything from the buffer, nothing is left to compact and it's `clear()`ed on each iteration anyways. Also, thanks for the hint on closing the channel. I'm aware that channels are kept open and that's intended. Clients may send new data anytime.

Comment: @riha Wrong. No client is ever going to send you any more data after you get the -1. That is end of stream on the channel, and it means the peer has closed the connection, or at least shut it down for output. Close it.

Comment: Hm ok, then it really should be closed on my side too. Though that's never ever supposed to happen in my case, but that's another story. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your result array is of length 0 and cannot hold any information. Byte arrays do not grow, and you are unable to append buffers' content. Use java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream to accumulate result.

Comment: Wrong. His result array is reassigned inside the loop.

Comment: Nice hint on `ByteArrayOutputStream`. That makes things waaay simpler.